# Creating a CNAME AWS RecordSet/Custom Domain connection to an API in SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, serverless, aws-sam

I am trying to use Route53 and Custom Domains to link a URL I have and the API gateway that is a Lambda Proxy underneath it.

This is what I have so far in my SAM file:

```
MyApiCertificate:
  Type: 'AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate'
  Properties:
    DomainName: example.com
MyApiDomainName:
  Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName'
  Properties:
    RegionalCertificateArn: !Ref MyApiCertificate
    DomainName: example.com
MyApiBasePathMapping:
  Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping'
  Properties:
    RestApiId: !Ref PublicApi
    DomainName: !Ref MyApiDomainName
    BasePath: /
    Stage: stage
MyApiRoute53RecordSetGroup:
  Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
  Properties:
    HostedZoneName: example.com
    RecordSets:
      - Name: example.com
        Type: A
        AliasTarget:
          EvaluateTargetHealth: false
          HostedZoneId: !GetAtt MyApiDomainName.DistributionHostedZoneId
          DNSName: !GetAtt MyApiDomainName.DistributionDomainName
```

I would like to make this of type CNAME and have the URL be stage.example.com

The following Code does not work.

```
MyApiCertificate:
  Type: 'AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate'
  Properties:
    DomainName: example.com
MyApiDomainName:
  Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName'
  Properties:
    RegionalCertificateArn: !Ref MyApiCertificate
    DomainName: example.com
MyApiBasePathMapping:
  Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::BasePathMapping'
  Properties:
    RestApiId: !Ref PublicApi
    DomainName: !Ref MyApiDomainName
    BasePath: /
    Stage: stage
MyApiRoute53RecordSetGroup:
  Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
  Properties:
    HostedZoneName: example.com
    RecordSets:
      - Name: stage.example.com
        Type: CNAME
        AliasTarget:
          EvaluateTargetHealth: false
          HostedZoneId: !GetAtt MyApiDomainName.DistributionHostedZoneId
          DNSName: !GetAtt MyApiDomainName.DistributionDomainName
```

I am getting this error: `Cannot import certificates for REGIONAL while EDGE is active. (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)`

Although nothing I have is an EDGE Api Gateway and Nothing has the name I want (Stage.example.com)

Any help on this issue would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same error using Terraform, and the issue was that I was specifying `regional_certificate_arn` rather than `certificate_arn`. API Gateway defaults to edge-optimized, which means you're specifying a `RegionalCertificateArn` with an edge-optimized API here - try using `CertificateArn` instead.